# variable value in class is not getting loaded properly

Tags: java, string, variables, global-variables

Below is my code snippet,this piece of code will be called from a workitem with the needed input parameters.The problem which Iam facing is the value of ExcpStatus variable is not getting loaded properly,my workitems will fail sometime and the value of finalOpStatus will be fail making the value of  ExcpStatus to YES.Now second time if i call this code (after ExcpStatus is changed to YES) the value of ExcpStatus should be reloaded as NO but it takes the previous changed value YES...Can someone help me in this....

```
     public abstract class SampleWorkItemHandler implements WorkItemHandler {

                public SampleWorkItemHandler()
                    {
                        this.sb_serviceTaskName="default";
                    }

                    public SampleWorkItemHandler(String taskName)
                    {
                        this.sb_serviceTaskName=taskName;
                    }
                    protected String ExcpStatus="NO";
                    protected String loggerCorrelationId = "";
                    private String  startLoggerInsertStr="";
               public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workitem, WorkItemManager manager) {
            try{
                logger.info("the exception staus is::"+ExcpStatus);
                logger.info("the loggerCorrelationId is::"+loggerCorrelationId);
                String finalOpStatus=SyntBotsBPMOutputValidatorUtil.validateResponse(handlerResponseParams);
                if(finalOpStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Fail"))
                {
                    ExcpStatus="YES";
                }
              }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Exception Stack Trace:::"+e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

Comment: What makes you think the variable should get reloaded as "NO" ? Are you using multiple instances of `SampleWorkItemHandler` ?

Comment: First Time if i trigger this class the value of ExcpStatus is NO but if the value is changed to YES and if I trigger the class second time then the value of ExcpStatus is still YES,but it should be NO right,since i have assigned the value to NO in the code.

Comment: *"it should be NO right,since i have assigned the value to NO in the code."* please show that part of the code too (including the place where you get the instance of `SampleWorkItemHandler`from).

Comment: Aside from initializing the ExcpStatus variable, where are you assigning it to "NO" ? I don't see this being done in the code you posted.

Comment: Also, not sure why you tagged `global-variables` since this code does not have any. Possibly, this is where the confusion lies.